# Downloading the HTML of the site returns something completely different

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to download the HTML of a webpage, but when I check the actual code of the web page and my downloaded code, they are completely different. Here is the code:

```
public static string getSourceCode(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string soruceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        resp.Close();
        return soruceCode;

        using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {

            // veriyi döndür
            return sRead.ReadToEnd();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string url = "http://www.booking.com/hotel/tr/nena.en-gb.html?label=gog235jc-hotel-en-tr-mina-nobrand-tr-com-T002-1;sid=fcc1c6c78f188a42870dcbe1cabf2fb4;dcid=1;origin=disamb;srhash=3938286438;srpos=5";
        string sourceCode = Finder.getSourceCode(url);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("HotelPrice.txt");//Here the code are completly different with web page code.
        sw.Write(sourceCode);
        sw.Close();

        #region //Get Score Value

        int StartIndex = sourceCode.IndexOf("<strong id=\"rsc_total\">") + 23;
        sourceCode = sourceCode.Substring(StartIndex, 3);

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: What's agent header are you sending. perhaps they are sending you a mobile version.

Comment: What do you mean by different? Is there any weird symbols? or browser's html source and downloaded string?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cause for the difference is that when you use the browser to request the same page it's part of a session which is not established when you request the same page using the WebRequest.

Looking at the URL it looks like that query parameter `sid` is a session identifier or a nonce of some sort. The page probably verifies that against the actually session id and when it determines that they are different it gives you some sort of "Ooopss.. wrong seesion" sort of response.

In order to mimic the browser's request you will have to make sure you generate the proper request which may need to include one or more of the following:

- cookies (previously sent to you by the webserver)
- a valid/proper user agent
- some specific query parameters (again depending on what the page expects)
- potentially a referrer URL
- authentication credentials

The best way to determine what you need is to follow a *conversation* between your browser and the web server serving that page from start to finish and see exactly which pages are requested, what order and what information is passed back and forth. You can accomplish this using WireShark or Fidler - both free tools!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when trying to use `HttpWebRequest` to crawl a page, and the page used `ajax` to load all the data I was after.  In order to get the `ajax` calls to occur I switched to the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx) control.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/1289454) provides an example of how to use the control outside of a WinForms app.  You'll want to hookup to the browser's `DocumentCompleted` event before parsing the page.  Be warned, this event may fire multiple times before the page is ready to be parsed.  You may want to add something like this

```
if(browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
```

to your event handler, to know when the page is completely done loading.